# C# Mysql Search in Form1 and show result in form2

Tags: c#, mysql

i have form1 that have searchToolStripTextBox, an invisible(visible=false) btnSearch, panel1(for loading form2) and dataToolStripMenuItem(showing form2). While form2 have dgvData(datagridview) which connected to mysql

the problem is i want to search someone name using searchToolStripTextBox(when i press enter, btnSearch will trigger) in form1 and form2 dgvData will select it

here's my code(in form1)

```
 private void dataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FData FD = new FData();
        FD.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        panel1.Controls.Add(FD);
        FD.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        FD.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        FD.Show();
        formtoolStripStatusLabel.Text = "Data";
    }

 private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FData FD = new FData();

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from tb_pasien where Pasien = '" + searchtoolStripTextBox.Text + "';";


            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            FD.dgvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Clone();
            }
        }
    }

    private void searchtoolStripTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            btnSearch_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    } 
}
```

thanks before.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're creating and showing a form in the `dataToolStripMenuItem_Click` method:

```
FData FD = new FData();
//...
FD.Show();
```

But then in the `btnSearch_Click` method you create *an entirely new form*, which you *never* show, and send your data to that one:

```
FData FD = new FData();
//...
FD.dgvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Changes made to an instance of an object don't affect *other* instances of that object.

Instead, make your form reference a class-level member.  Something like this:

```
FData FD = new FData();

private void dataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    FD.Show();
}

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    FD.dgvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

That way there's only *one* instance of the `FData` form and you're both showing *and* interacting with that same instance.

Answer (score -1):

You're creating a new instance of FD when clicking search. You should use the same instance that you created in the first method in the second method. You can do that by defining a class field:

```
FData FD;
private void dataToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FD = new FData();
}
```

And remove this line in the search function:

```
FData FD = new FData();
```

You might need also to do a *NULL* check in the Search function for object `FD`.

Comment: @Celcius_Bitz `if(DF != null)`. I don't really know if that is a case in your process, but it is helpful to check for an object that you're not 100% sure that is initialized.